# ANR error after crash

Tags: android

I add Activity to activityStack when Activiy execute Oncreate.
crash. Finish All Activity in UncaughtExceptionHandler.

```
public void finishAllActivity() {
    Activity activity;
    while(!activityStack.empty()){
        activity = activityStack.pop();
        activity.finish();
    }
}
```

log:

```
12-05 10:35:38.515: D/testException(13404): com.orimuse.android.activity.message.FirendCircleActivity finish!
12-05 10:35:38.517: D/testException(13404): com.orimuse.android.activity.homepage.MainActivity_ finish!
12-05 10:35:39.017: W/ActivityManager(752): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{39eba0cf u0 com.orimuse.android/.activity.message.FirendCircleActivity t2550 f}
12-05 10:35:40.029: W/PackageManager(1499): Failure retrieving resources for com.orimuse.android: Resource ID #0x0
12-05 10:35:48.525: W/ActivityManager(752): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{21cd14af u0 com.orimuse.android/.activity.homepage.MainActivity_ t2550 f}
12-05 10:35:49.381: W/ActivityManager(752): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{39eba0cf u0 com.orimuse.android/.activity.message.FirendCircleActivity t2550 f}
12-05 10:36:11.756: E/WifiStateMachine(752): WifiStateMachine starting scan for "orimuse-5"WPA_PSK with 5745,2412
12-05 10:36:31.762: E/WifiStateMachine(752): WifiStateMachine starting scan for "orimuse-5"WPA_PSK with 5745,2412
12-05 10:36:38.896: W/BroadcastQueue(752): Receiver during timeout: ResolveInfo{26e76784 com.orimuse.android/.activity.xg.MyPushReceiver m=0x108000}
12-05 10:36:43.186: E/ActivityManager(752): ANR in com.orimuse.android
12-05 10:36:43.186: E/ActivityManager(752): Reason: Broadcast of Intent { act=com.tencent.android.tpush.action.FEEDBACK flg=0x10 pkg=com.orimuse.android cmp=com.orimuse.android/.activity.xg.MyPushReceiver (has extras) }
```

The problem is in Destroying Activity or MyPushReceiver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your app have a BroadcastReceiver.

Your onReceive() method in BroadcastReceiver works longer than 10s, while it must finish earlier (note that onReceive() of a BroadcastReceiver is called on the main application thread)